# Command to change variable name conventions in sublime text 2

Tags: sublimetext2

I want to change text such a way

someSpecialVariable <-> some_special_variable

Does anyone know command in sublime text 2 for this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the [`Case Conversion`](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/Case%20Conversion) plugin. It adds to the **`Edit -> Convert Case`** menu, and includes `snake_case`, `camelCase`, `PascalCase`, `dot.case`, `dash-case`, and options to `separate words` and place `slashes/between/words`.

Comment: @PavelKostikov glad I could help. To indicate that this answer solved your problem, please click the check mark next to it to mark it as "accepted". Please see [*What does it mean when an answer is "accepted"?*](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) for more information. Also, since you now have over 15 [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) points, you may choose to upvote it if you wish. Both actions are completely optional, of course.